# TXW.create() different behavior on jdk and android?

Tags: android, xml, web-services, cxf

I've created webservice on desktop (jdk, working good) and i'm trying to move it to android (make it running on android device). But i'm having some issues and after debugging for few days i've found different behaviour of the next code:

`Schema schema = TXW.create(Schema.class,ResultFactory.createSerializer(result));`

Passed `result` object is almost empty before invocation and has only `systemId` property. On JDK created schema has not null `nsUri` property, but on Android it's just empty!

JDK:
[image]

Android:
[image]

What's the reason and how can i fix it?
It makes schema invalid and it throws exception in cxf later:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace: schema
```

**Update1:**

I'v found `TXW` code `pkg.getAnnotation(XmlNamespace.class)` return `null` in android but instance value in jdk:

```
if(nsUri.equals("##default")) {
            Package pkg = c.getPackage();
            if(pkg!=null) {
                XmlNamespace xn = pkg.getAnnotation(XmlNamespace.class); // xn = null in android
                if(xn!=null)
                    nsUri = xn.value();
            }
        }
        if(nsUri.equals("##default"))
            nsUri = "";

        return new QName(nsUri,localName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in `TXW.java`:

```
Package pkg = c.getPackage();
XmlNamespace xn = pkg.getAnnotation(XmlNamespace.class);
if(xn!=null) // always null in android as it does not support package annotations
    nsUri = xn.value();
```

So i had to hack it - create public static variable and set it before:

```
public static java.lang.String XmlNamespaceAnnotationValue = null;
...
Package pkg = c.getPackage();
if(pkg!=null) {
    if (XmlNamespaceAnnotationValue != null) {
        nsUri = XmlNamespaceAnnotationValue;
    } else {
         XmlNamespace xn = pkg.getAnnotation(XmlNamespace.class);
         if(xn!=null)
             nsUri = xn.value();
    }
}
```

Before usage:

```
TXW.XmlNamespaceAnnotationValue = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
```